# Jetpack Compose - How to control IME (keyboard) in a scrollable non-lazy column?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

According to https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/ we can use a nested scroll connection to control the keyboard appearance when scrolling.

[image: scrolling kb]

The [sample code](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/insets/ImeAnimationSample.kt) has the modern impl for a LazyColumn:

```
LazyColumn(
    reverseLayout = true,
    modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .nestedScroll(connection = rememberImeNestedScrollConnection())
    ) {
        items(listItems) { imageUrl -> ListItem(imageUrl, Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
    }
}
```

The doc has a sample for `ScrollableColumn`  which is no longer a thing as of beta06:

```
// Here we're using ScrollableColumn, but it also works with LazyColumn, etc.
ScrollableColumn(
    // We use the nestedScroll modifier, passing in the 
    // the connection from rememberImeNestedScrollConnection()
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(
        connection = rememberImeNestedScrollConnection()
    )
) {
    // list content
}
```

What is the equivalent for `Modifier.verticalScroll()`?  I've tried combining it with `nestedScroll()` to no effect.

```
val imeNestedScrollConnection = rememberImeNestedScrollConnection()

Column(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .nestedScroll(imeNestedScrollConnection)
        .padding(horizontal = spacing, vertical = 8.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) { ... }
```

Other things I've tried

- Changing the order of the two scroll modifiers (no difference)
- Having only the nestedScroll modifier (column no longer scrolls at all)

Answer (score 1):

```
LazyColumn(
           modifier = Modifier
              .fillMaxSize()
              .statusBarsPadding() // <-- To avoid obscuring content by status bar.
              .imePadding() // <-- To avoid obscuring content
              .imeNestedScroll() // <-- This does the trick with LazyColumn
              .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.statusBars),
           content = {/** Some composable for content */}
)
```